# Unit test C# console application ('using' not working)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, using

I am working with Visual Studio 2015. I have created a new C# console application and a new Unit Test Project. I want to connect the two of them, to be able to do unit tests. I have added a reference to the console application in the Unit Test Project. But when I try to add the `using` statement, it does not pop up in Intelli-Sense.

With a **class library** instead of a **console application**, this worked fine. Why doesn't this work, and how do I get it to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there at least 1 public class in the namespace you are adding?

Comment: It's hard to tell from distance. Are you able to create a minimal project for which the test project does not work as expected?

Comment: So its the lack of intellisense? What if you manually type the class name, does that resolve and compile?

Comment: @RB. It is a new console application. There is a class, but it's privacy is not set. It's like the main class. I tried adding public in front of it, but this did not solve it.

Comment: @LDJ I tried typing it manually, but then it still doesn't work. If I then try to call the Main function in the main class (called 'Program' by default), it shows an error: "The name 'Program' does not exist in the current context".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is a combination of all your answers/comments.
IntelliSense does not show the Console App. I don't know why, maybe because there is no public class yet. I can type it manually. It won't work calling main or the main class (called 'Program'). But if I create a public class with a constructor, I can call it from the unit test.
So, basically, my template works, and can now be used to build my future TDD projects on.

Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new public class in console application, where you will write your functionality, after that you need to create an instance of this class in the unit test and test the functionality. 
Class Programm its an entry point which parses the arguments, so you dont need to have there any logic and also you dont need to test it.

Comment: I am a student, doing many different small projects. As I want to work with TDD, I would like to create a template with Unit Test and Console Application already linked together.

Comment: OK. You need to create, for example, class Calculator.
 You create test for the Sum - run it. It will not passed. After that you create a method Sum in the Calculator class and run your test - it will be passed.
 At the end create an instance of calculator in the main method`var calc = new Calculator()` and call the method Sum `calc.Sum(2,4)`.